# My Android AdMod ad is blank in test mode

Tags: android, webview, admob

I am trying to display admod ads on my android app. Instad of writing java code, I was going to use a WevView that displayed a web page with the following code
TED

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var admob_vars = {
  pubid: 'Mu Publisher id is here', //
  bgcolor: '000000', // background color (hex)
  text: 'FFFFFF', // font-color (hex)
  test: true // test mode, set to false if non-test mode
 };
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mm.admob.com/static/iphone/iadmob.js"></script>
```

The WebView only displays TED and no test message.

- Ted

Answer (score 0):

A webview doesn't by default support javascript.

you can use:

> webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

to enable javascript in a webview.

(I know I might be a tad late but google overlords redirected me to this page while I was looking for a similar problem ;-))