# Android AdMob returning blank, not clickable ads (picture and small log included)

Tags: android, admob

A few days ago, I started having problems with **AdMob**. They return **blank ads** (a view with nothing on it). I also noticed that they are **not clickable** (in case that detail helps).

As such my revenue dropped almost completely (to a few cents per app), CTR dropped and all that. I noticed that it started happening some day with no reason on the previous SDK (4.0.4 IIRC). I tried uploading a version with the new SDK (4.1), but still have problems.

Despite all that, **it still works *sometimes***, which leaves me wondering...

Questions here on SO and on the Internet [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6090261/admob-ads-not-clickable-and-not-displaying-well-urgent), [2](http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/c9219ceadb6f5e62?pli=1) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060672/my-android-admod-ad-is-blank-in-test-mode) (this one isn't Android, but still...)] didn't help much.

Screenshot:

[image: blank AdMob ad]

Log follows. I'm intrigued with the last warning (I indented), as I suspect that's the problem... and I have no idea of what it means.

```
06-09 08:44:16.730: INFO/Ads(27033): To get test ads on this device, call adRequest.addTestDevice("1355EC5CAF8FDBFF50FFE95E7C3187E9");
06-09 08:44:16.800: WARN/InputManagerService(110): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@40759998 (uid=10071 pid=27033)
06-09 08:44:16.800: WARN/InputManagerService(110): Client not active, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@407f8418
06-09 08:44:16.906: INFO/Ads(27033): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script src="http://www.gstatic.com/afma/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":1,"u_sd":1.5,"slotname":"b23d5315c744d5a","u_w":320,"msid":"com.dc.test","js":"afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0","isu":"1355EC5CAF8FDBFF50FFE95E7C3187E9","format":"320x50_mb","net":"wi","app_name":"12.android.com.dc.test","hl":"pt","u_h":533,"u_audio":1,"u_so":"p"});</script></head><body></body></html>
06-09 08:44:17.050: INFO/ActivityManager(110): Displayed com.dc.test/.ui.MainActivity: +495ms (total +45s519ms)
06-09 08:44:17.500: INFO/Ads(27033): Received ad url: <"url": "http://r.admob.com:80/ad_source.php?preqs=1&u_sd=1.5&slotname=b23d5315c744d5a&u_w=320&msid=com.dc.test&js=afma-sdk-a-v4.1.0&isu=1355EC5CAF8FDBFF50FFE95E7C3187E9&format=320x50_mb&net=wi&app_name=12.android.com.dc.test&hl=pt-BR&u_h=533&u_audio=1&u_so=p&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=180&ex=1&client_sdk=1&askip=1", "afmaNotifyDt": "null">
    06-09 08:44:18.097: WARN/webcore(27033): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
06-09 08:44:18.101: INFO/Ads(27033): onReceiveAd()
```

After this I get standard dalvikvm stuff, so I guess it ends here. I can include more details if needed. I didn't include code because I didn't change anything for that to start happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was just a temporary problem. Not something I (we?) could fix I believe. It seems to have returned to normal with my app.

Thanks for answering, DynamicMind.

Answer (score 1):

Check your add mob account and also check the version of the ADMob SDK.
It may be possible to it happens for some time. Also try on another device .
May be it is helpful to you.

Comment: The admob version is the current version (4.1). And yes, I'm testing on my device right now (I will see on others later), but considering the sharp drop in revenue and CTR, I believe it's safe to guess that my users may be experiencing the same problem. But then again, *maybe*. Thanks!